# How to Implement Two Dependent Firestore onSnapshot Listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a Firebase web app where users collaboratively edit and share recent hot news topics in small chunks (less than 1,000 characters) that we call "nodes". Each user can pin some nodes to show them on their UI while posting/editing other nodes.

We have defined the following two Firestore collections:

- `nodes`: includes the content (text, image, ...), last `dateTime` modified, ....
- `pins`: includes `nodeId` and `userId` of the user who pinned the node with `nodeId`, a flag of whether they `pinned`, and `dateTime`.

There are so many nodes in our database and defining an `onSnapshot` listener on `nodes` makes our web app very slow. So, we only define an `onSnapshot` listener for `pins` and query only the nodes that the user has pinned one by one.

The problem is that the nodes may get updated by other users frequently, and we should update them on the UI accordingly. We don't think it's a good idea to incrementally define `onSnapshot` listeners for every node that the user pins because they may be many. What is an efficient solution to this problem?

One solution we thought of was to combine the two collections into the `nodes` collection; define `pins` as an array of `userId`s in each document; and in the `nodes` `onSnapshot` listener, restrict the query to only `nodes` with the authenticated `userId` included in their `pins` array. The issue with this approach is that the number of users who pin a hot node may increase significantly and the `node` document may get too large. [The Firestore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas) defines the "Maximum size for a document" as 1 MiB. Considering that we have multiple types of user interactions with nodes such as voting, commenting, ... which are similar to pinning, defining all of them in the node documents may not be feasible.

Comment: Realtime database might be a better option for this imo since most of things are changing so frequently.

Comment: Why? The Firestore documentation says: "Cloud Firestore is Firebase's newest database for mobile app development. It builds on the successes of the Realtime Database with a new, more intuitive data model. Cloud Firestore also features richer, faster queries and scales further than the Realtime Database." https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: The same page also says, "Realtime Database is Firebase's original database. It's an efficient, low-latency solution for mobile apps that require synced states across clients in realtime." There are few questions on that page that might help you choose between either depending on your use case.

Comment: Questions like these that are more open ended are better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, according to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68386/1146903). You can try posting there to get the right attention your question needs.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for letting me know. However, because my question is specifically about Firebase, I'd appreciate it if you let me keep my questions here as well.